# JQuery image highlighting function not working when using a modal popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, modalpopupextender

I'm using an external JS function called maphilight see (http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/)

It draws wonderfully when using it on an imageMap, unless the imageMap is placed inside a modalPopupExtender, which makes it not visible at all..

I have no idea what the problem could be, so any help would be absolutely fantastic as I am pulling my hair out over this !

Thanks! :)

Working maphighlight js:

```
<asp:ImageMap id="mapAssets" runat="server" HotSpotMode="Navigate" ImageUrl="image" ClientIDMode="Static" style="opacity:0.3; filter:alpha(opacity=40);" >
    <asp:RectangleHotSpot Top="390" Left="367" Right="707" Bottom="609" AlternateText=".."  HotSpotMode="PostBack"  />


</asp:ImageMap>
```

Not working JS:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnabc" runat="server" />


<cc1:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" ID="ModalPopupExtender1" TargetControlID="btnabc" PopupControlID="pnltest"  
            CancelControlID="btnCancel"  ClientIDMode="Static" >

</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel id="pnltest" runat="server" BackColor="Transparent" style="opacity:0.4;">

<asp:ImageMap id="mapAssets" runat="server" HotSpotMode="Navigate" ImageUrl="image" ClientIDMode="Static" style="opacity:0.3; filter:alpha(opacity=40);" >
    <asp:RectangleHotSpot Top="390" Left="367" Right="707" Bottom="609" AlternateText="..."  HotSpotMode="PostBack"  />


</asp:ImageMap>

</asp:Panel>
```